# scheduled tasks running in %systemroot%\system32\

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-task

I have a scheduled task that calls a bat file, problem is it does this in c:\windows\system32 instead of the path it exists in (c:\bak), is there a setting that I can change to set it to run in the correct location?

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps you should simply **add a command at the start of the script to set the correct working directory** and other environment settings?  Scripts that don't work every time can drive someone else trying to fix your script insane if they don't know what the environment should be like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - in the "Edit Action" UI, fill out the **Start In (Optional)** field.

(If you aren't already, use the Task Scheduler to create your scheduled task.)

Comment: @Beuy - my pleasure, I've got several tasks set up and have had to deal with the differences between this incarnation of task scheduling and previous ones. :)